# Remove duplicates from array based on date

Tags: powershell

In powershell I have an array that I've imported from CSV with the following information

```
UserName           RecordDate 
@{UserName=user1;  RecordDate=05/18/2013}
@{UserName=user1;  RecordDate=05/18/2012}
@{UserName=user1;  RecordDate=04/18/2013}
@{UserName=user1;  RecordDate=01/18/2013}
@{UserName=user22; RecordDate=05/18/2013}
@{UserName=user22; RecordDate=05/18/2012}
@{UserName=user22; RecordDate=04/18/2013}
@{UserName=user22; RecordDate=01/18/2013}
```

I want to remove the duplicated entries based on date and leave only the entry with the latest date for each user in username

Thank you!!

Comment: How did you import them from csv? Depending on the way it's done the type of the resulting objects can be different and the way to filter them will also be different because of that. Could you please post your code.

Comment: I've added the commands i've used so far to the original post

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new or followup question: post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Import-Csv "C:\path\to\your.csv" `
  | select UserName, @{
      n='RecordDate';
      e={[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.RecordDate, 'MM\/dd\/yyyy', $null)}
    } `
  | group UserName `
  | % { $_.Group | sort RecordDate -Desc | select -First 1 }
```

Comment: the sorting seems to be wrong because the date format is mm/dd/yyyy
what can i do about it ?

Comment: this is the commands i use so far $settings_array = @("Username", "RecordDate"); $csv = Import-Csv $currentWorkFile | Select $settings_array | group UserName | % {$_.Group | sort RecordDate -Desc | select -First 1 }

Comment: Cast the field to a date in the `sort` statement as suggested by [@zdan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17714538/1630171) (+1) or parse the date string into an actual date in the `select` statement (see updated answer).

Comment: Awesome guys its worked !!!
thank you very much for all the help, i really need to improve my powershell skills...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert your property to a `DateTime` so that it's sorted properly. Just change the sort to look like this:

```
sort {[DateTime]$_.RecordDate}
```